# C#: Use Task<> inside Tuple

Tags: c#, async-await

This would work if I remove `Tuple` and just using `Task<bool>` or `Task<string>`.

```
 public async Tuple<Task<bool>, string> Test()
        {

            //....

            return new Tuple<Task<bool>, string>(false, "a string");
        }
```

Any idea how to make this work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Async method should return `void` (bad practice) or `Task` or `Task<T>` (see [Return Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156513.aspx) section). In your case I believe it should be

```
public async Task<Tuple<bool, string>> Test()
{
    // await ...
    return Tuple.Create(false, "a string");
}
```

Comment: @user7399041 - Or if you really want to return a `Tuple<Task<bool>, string>`, just remove the `async` modifier and pass an actual `Task` to the first parameter of the `Tuple` constructor.

Comment: @sellotape yep, if method is not async, then you can return `Tuple`. But OP tries to create tuple with `false, "a string"`. That's why I thought he actually wants to return tuple from async method :)

Comment: Agreed.  He could return `Task.FromResult(false)` in that case, although I assumed it was just a very cut down example without real code.  Over to him as to what he really wants to do...